# Pass data object back and forth between Qt Gui and a python console

Tags: python, pyqt, ipython

I have a (PyQt4) GUI application that handles some specific data objects. 
It enables the user  to read, edit, plot and analyze such a data object using a graphic interface. Now I would like to be able to launch (from the GUI) some commandline/(i)python session where I can manipulate the very same data object. In the end I want to be able to easily switch between GUI-based and commandline-based manipulating and the changes made should be available in both modes.

My first (and only) idea would be to pickle the data object upon pressing a button, launching an ipython session with a init-script that unpickles the object and manually repickle the object once done in commandline mode and unpickle it back to the GUI. However I don't think this would be very unstable.

Comment: Perhaps embedding the `qtconsole` in your program is an option. This used to be part of of IPython but the terminal and kernel functionality has been split into the Jupyter project. [Here](http://jupyter.org/qtconsole/stable/#embedding-the-qtconsole-in-a-qt-application) is some information about embedding. The fourth option (InProcessKernel), looks the most promising to me. However, I don't know how to put your variables into this kernel. Let me now if you succeed.